# process.terminate() doesn't work for a chrome / firefox subprocess if a browser window is already present

Tags: python, subprocess, kill-process

I am launching a sub-process using the following command:

```
p=subprocess.Popen(["google-chrome","--new-window","http://www.hckrnews.com"])
```

I need to kill this process after sometime, so I'm using:

```
time.sleep(t)
p.terminate()
```

This works only if no instance of the browser is already open. If a browser window is already present, a new window opens but does not terminate after specified time.

I also tried the method given in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true), but that also doesn't work in case of already present window.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is **not** a python problem, and your code doesn't contain errors. It's a problem with the browsers. When you launch the firefox or chrome's executable with `--new-window` a new window is opened **in the existing instance** of the browser.

In other words the process you just started connects to the already existing process of firefox/chrome and instructs *that* process to open a new window and then terminates. So when you call `terminate()` nothing really happens because the process you started already ended.

You can check this with few lines of code:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['firefox', '-new-window'])
>>> p.wait()   # uh-oh. this should be blocking!
0
>>> p.terminate()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1551, in terminate
    self.send_signal(signal.SIGTERM)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1546, in send_signal
    os.kill(self.pid, sig)
OSError: [Errno 3] No such process
```

You should tell the browser to open a new instance instead of a new window. Firefox has a `-new-instance` option, even though, when trying to use it, the only thing I get is that a pop-up appears saying that I cannot open two instances of the browser. Whether opening multiple instances of a browser in a certain OS session is allowed depends on the browser and *may not be possible*.

On Chrome I believe you can open a new session telling Chrome to use a different directory to store its data (see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35392/how-to-launch-a-new-instance-of-google-chrome-from-the-command-line) for example). No idea whether this is possible
 in firefox.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll try using Chrome with a different directory for user data. Also, it doesn't make sense that Firefox has a -new-instance option but doesn't allow to open multiple instances!

Comment: @quasistatic : multiple instances are allowed, it's just that they must use different profiles.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in [Bakuriu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25606576/21945), `--new-window` creates a new window, but under an existing instance of firefox, if there is one. If there is no existing instance, a new one is created.

It is possible to use `-new-instance` to tell Firefox to start a new instance for a *different* firefox user profile. The profile must already exist and this is limited to one instance per profile. A new profile can be created interactively with `firefox -P -new-instance`, and a new instance can then be started with `firefox -P <profile_name> -new-instance`. Mozilla's profile documentation is [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles).

It should be possible to programmatically create the profile - after all it is just a directory and an entry in the `~/.mozilla/profiles.ini` file. Of course, this is for Firefox only, chrome might be completely different (or impossible?). An example:

```
import tempfile
import subprocess
import shutil
import time
import ConfigParser

MOZILLA_PROFILES_INI = '.mozilla/firefox/profiles.ini'
PROFILE_SECTION = 'Profile1'

URL = 'http://www.hckrnews.com'
profile_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()

# quick and dirty add new profile to profiles.ini, or update if already present.
config = ConfigParser.SafeConfigParser()
config.optionxform = str         # preserve case of option names
config.read(MOZILLA_PROFILES_INI)
try:
    config.add_section(PROFILE_SECTION)
except ConfigParser.DuplicateSectionError, exc:
    pass

config.set(PROFILE_SECTION, 'Name', 'temp_profile')
config.set(PROFILE_SECTION, 'IsRelative', '0')
config.set(PROFILE_SECTION, 'Path', profile_dir)

# write out config with hack to remove added spaces around '=' - more care needed here as it just overwrites the global mozilla config!
class NoSpaceWriter(file):
    def write(self, s):
        super(NoSpaceWriter, self).write(s.replace(' = ', '='))

with NoSpaceWriter(MOZILLA_PROFILES_INI, 'w') as profiles_ini:
   config.write(profiles_ini)

p = subprocess.Popen(['firefox', '-P', 'temp_profile', '-new-instance', URL])
time.sleep(10)
p.terminate()

shutil.rmtree(profile_dir, True)
```